# Error to getting response while sending ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm new to Ajax. I'm writing two function in one file called `home.php` and make an Ajax call to `members.php`.

My problem is when I send an data with ajax call I fail to get response.

home.php

---

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        var httpObject=false;
        var httpObject1=false;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            httpObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
            httpObject1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else if(window.ActiveXObject){
            httpObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
            httpObject1 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
        }
        function logout(){

            if(httpObject.readyState == 4 && httpObject.status == 200){
                    var response = httpObject.responseText;

                    if(response == "logout"){
                        window.location.href="index.php";

                    }
                    else{
                        error.innerHTML = "Sorry, Invalid Login.";
                    }
                }
        }

        function get_Request_Member_List(type){

            var member_Type = type;
            var queryString = "?data1=" + member_Type ;
            if(httpObject1.readyState == 4 && httpObject1.status == 200){
                    var response = httpObject1.responseText;
                    document.getElementById(type).innerHTML = response;
            }

        }

        httpObject.open("GET", "logout.php" ,true);
        httpObject.send(null);

        httpObject1.open("GET", "members.php"+queryString ,true);
        httpObject1.send(null);
    </script>
```

members.php

---

```
<?php
echo "hello";
?>
```

Comment: How do you call logout() and get_Request_Member_List() functions?

Comment: I do it on <body onload='get_Request_Member_List("requests")'>

Comment: Move your open() and send() lines to this function. After this line: var queryString = ...

Comment: I tried that way also it doesn't work

Comment: Check httpObject1.readyState and httpObject1.status values using alert().

Comment: httpObject1.open("GET", "members.php"+queryString ,true);

Comment: httpObject1.open("GET", "members.php?type=request" ,true);

Comment: httpObject1.open("GET", "members.php?type=request" ,true); This way only the response received

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add an `onreadystatechange` event handler to your XMLHTTPRequest, e.g.:

```
httpObject.onreadystatechange = logout;
```

Comment: This is not necessary if request is synchronous.

Comment: where i put this and why?